# Broken link leading to 400 error

Tags: bug, status-completed

Apparently the link to the profile of the user who submitted the picture is broken! Unnecessary escape characters dancing!.

#### Steps to replicate

1. Go to https://photo.stackexchange.com/
2. On the top bar, next to the Hall of Fame picture, click on the user's name.
   [image]

Now you will get a **Bad Request - Invalid URL** error!

The link's href value is `https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/%0D%0A31835/himanshu-tyagi`.

It should be `https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/31835/himanshu-tyagi`

Comment: Weird. That's a carriage return + line feed pair.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, my bad. Thanks for pointing it out. Have corrected it.